# implement General Update Pattern for d3.js force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Beginning with [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mfolnovic/6269308) (possibly not the best choice), I set about trying to develop an application to suit my purposes, and learn d3.js in the process. After a lot of naive tinkering, I managed to get a [toy force layout](http://neolography.com/d3charters) for my test data that satisfied me in its appearance and behavior. Now I've set about trying to understand MB's [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) in the context of my particular example, so that users can interactively modify the graph. I clearly have not yet grasped the principle.

Starting small, I thought to create a function that would simply add a single additional link to the graph between the nodes labeled "Walteri" and "Roberti de Fonte" (there's a button that executes `addedge()`, or you can execute it from the js console). In a broken sort of way, this had the desired result; however, the existing graph remained in place while a duplicate graph was generated containing the additional link. It's clear that there is something about the General Update Pattern that I'm still not understanding.

If anyone has a look and can offer any insight, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/d3-force-layout-internals)?

Comment: The [force layout](http://neolography.com/d3charters) mentioned above has been updated with the changes offered by @coolblue in the accepted answer below. That online example will not persist long, but careful reading of coolblue's commented code below (many thanks!) will help illuminate MB's General Update Pattern for d3.js and its application to the force layout.

Comment: With the insight provided by @coolblue in the accepted answer, I started again from scratch using [this example from MB](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) as a model. The [force layout](http://neolography.com/d3charters/) example mentioned above has been updated with pared down data, and now satisfactorily demonstrates importing new graph data via `d3.json()` and programmatically adding individual edges between nodes. Thanks again @coolblue. I'll leave this up for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Managing Updates**
The main issue you have is that you are re-appending your group elements every update.
You can get d3 to manage that for you like this...

```
//Nodes bag
//UPDATE
var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
            .data(["circles_g"]);
//ENTER
circles.enter()
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "circles");
```

You just need to make up a one element array to drive it.  The nice thing about that is it will be placed on the `__data__` member which is added to the `g` element by d3, so its handy for debugging as well.

**General Pattern**
Generally speaking, this is the most defensive pattern...

```
//UPDATE
var update = baseSelection.selectAll(elementSelector)
            .data(values, key),
    //ENTER
        enter = update.enter().append(appendElement)
            .call(initStuff),
    //enter() has side effect of adding enter nodes to the update selection
    //so anything you do to update now will include the enter nodes

    //UPDATE+ENTER
        updateEnter = update
            .call(stuffToDoEveryTimeTheDataChanges);
    //EXIT
    exit = update.exit().remove()
```

First time through `update` will be an array of nulls with the same structure as the data.
The `.selectAll()` returns a zero length selection in this case and does nothing useful.

On subsequent updates, `.selectAll` will not be empty and will be compared to `values`, using `keys`, to determine which nodes are update, enter and exit nodes.  That's why you need the select before the data join.

The important thing to understand is that it has to be `.enter().append(...)`, so you are appending elements on the enter selection.  If you append them on the update selection (the one returned by the data join) then you will re-enter the same elements and see similar behaviour to what you are getting.

The enter selection is an array of simple objects of the form `{ __data__: data }`
The update and exit selections are arrays of arrays of references to DOM elements.

The data method in d3 keeps a closure on the enter and exit selections which are accessed by `.enter()` and `.exit()` methods on `update`.    Both return objects which, among other things, are 2-D arrays (All selections in d3 are arrays of groups, where groups are arrays of nodes.). 
the `enter` member is also given a reference to `update` so that it can merge the two.  This is done because, in the majority of cases, the same stuff is done to both groups.

**Revised Code**
There was a strange bug where links disappeared sometimes when an edge was added which was unrelated but was due to `NaN`'s in `d.x` and `d.y` in the nodes.
If you don't rebuild the force layout every time in `showme` and if you do this...

```
links.push({ "source": nodes[i], "target": nodes[j], "type": "is_a_tenant_of" });
force.start();
showme();
```

the bug goes away and everything works fine.

> This is because the internal state for the layout does not include the
>   extra links, particularly the `strengths` and `distances` arrays.  The
>   internal `force.tick()` method uses these to calculate the new link
>   lengths and if there are more links than members of these arrays, then
>   they will return `undefined` and the link, length calculation will
>   return `NaN` and this is then multiplied by the node `x` and `y`
>   values to calculate the new `d.x` and `d.y`.
>   This is all recalculated in `force.start()`

Also, you can move `force = d3.layout.force()....start();` into a separate `function` and only call it once at the start.

```
d3.json("force-directed-edges.json", function(error, data){
        if (error) return console.warn(error)
                nodes = data.nodes, 
                links = data.links,
                predicates = data.predicates,
                json = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);

                for (n in nodes) { // don't want to require incoming data to have links array for each node
                        nodes[n].links = []
                }

                links.forEach(function(link, i) {
                        // kept the 'Or' check, in case we're building the nodes only from the links
                        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
                        link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = { name: link.target });
                        // To do any dijkstra searching, we'll need adjacency lists: node.links. (easier than I thought)
                        link.source.links.push(link);
                        link.target.links.push(link);
                });

                nodes = d3.values(nodes);
                reStart()
                showme();
});

function randomNode(i) {
    var j;
    do {
        j = Math.round(Math.random() * (nodes.length - 1))
    } while (j === (i ? i : -1))
    return j
}
function addedge() {
    var i = randomNode(), j = randomNode(i);

    links.push({ "source": nodes[i], "target": nodes[j], "type": "is_a_tenant_of" });
    force.start();
    showme();
}

function reStart() {
    force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .size([w, h])
        .linkDistance(function (link) {
            var wt = link.target.weight;
            return wt > 2 ? wt * 10 : 60;
        })
        .charge(-600)
        .gravity(.01)
        .friction(.75)
        //.theta(0)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();
}
function showme() {
    //Marker Types  
    var defs = svg.selectAll("defs")
                .data(["defs"], function (d) { return d }).enter()
                .append("svg:defs")
                    .selectAll("marker")
                        .data(predicates)
                        .enter().append("svg:marker")
                            .attr("id", String)
                            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
                            .attr("refX", 30)
                            .attr("refY", 0)
                            .attr("markerWidth", 4)
                            .attr("markerHeight", 4)
                            .attr("orient", "auto")
                        .append("svg:path")
                            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5"),
    //Link bag
            //UPDATE
            paths = svg.selectAll(".paths")
                .data(["paths_g"]);
            //ENTER
    paths.enter()
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "paths");

    //Links
    //UPDATE
    path = paths.selectAll("path")
        .data(links);
    //ENTER
    path.enter()
        .append("svg:path");
    //UPDATE+ENTER
    path
        .attr("indx", function (d, i) { return i })
        .attr("id", function (d) { return d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index; })
        .attr("class", function (d) { return "link " + d.type; })
        .attr("marker-end", function (d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });
    //EXIT          
    path.exit().remove();

    //Link labels bag
    //UPDATE
    var path_labels = svg.selectAll(".labels")
            .data(["labels_g"]);
            //ENTER
    path_labels.enter()
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "labels");

    //Link labels
            //UPDATE
    var path_label = path_labels.selectAll(".path_label")
                .data(links);
            //ENTER
    path_label.enter()
        .append("svg:text")
            .append("svg:textPath")
                .attr("startOffset", "50%")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("fill", "#000")
                .style("font-family", "Arial");
            //UPDATE+ENTER
    path_label
        .attr("class", function (d, i) { return "path_label " + i })
//EDIT*******************************************************************
      .selectAll('textPath')
//EDIT*******************************************************************
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "#" + d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.type; }),
    //EXIT
    path_label.exit().remove();

    //Nodes bag
            //UPDATE
    var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
                .data(["circles_g"]);
            //ENTER
    circles.enter()
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "circles");

    //Nodes
    //UPDATE
    circle = circles.selectAll(".nodes")
                .data(nodes);
    //ENTER
    circle.enter().append("svg:circle")
                .attr("class", function (d) { return "nodes " + d.index })
                .attr("stroke", "#000");
    //UPDATE+ENTER
    circle
        .on("click", clicked)
        .on("dblclick", dblclick)
        .on("contextmenu", cmdclick)
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
            console.log(i + " " + d.types[0] + " " + node_colors[d.types[0]])
            return node_colors[d.types[0]];
        })
        .attr("r", function (d) { return d.types.indexOf("Document") == 0 ? 24 : 12; })
        .call(force.drag);
    //EXIT
    circle.exit().remove();

    //Anchors bag
    //UPDATE
    var textBag = svg.selectAll(".anchors")
                .data(["anchors_g"]);
            //ENTER
            textBag.enter()
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "anchors"),

    //Anchors
            //UPDATE
            textUpdate = textBag.selectAll("g")
                .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.name; }),
    //ENTER
    textEnter = textUpdate.enter()
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", function (d) { return "anchors " + d.index });

    // A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
    textEnter.append("svg:text")
                .attr("x", 8)
                .attr("y", ".31em")
                .attr("class", "shadow")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

    textEnter.append("svg:text")
                .attr("x", 8)
                .attr("y", ".31em")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; });
    textUpdate.exit().remove();
    text = textUpdate;

    // calling force.drag() here returns the drag _behavior_ on which to set a listener
    // node element event listeners
    force.drag().on("dragstart", function (d) {
        d3.selectAll(".dbox").style("z-index", 0);
        d3.select("#dbox" + d.index).style("z-index", 1);
    })
}
```

**EDIT**
In response to the comment below from @jjon and for my own edification, here is the minimum changes from the original code with same naming conventions and differential comments.  The mods required for properly adding links are unchanged and not discussed...

```
function showme() {
    svg
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Problem
    //  another defs element is added to the document every update
    //Solution:
    //  create a data join on defs 
    //  append the marker definitions on the resulting enter selection
    //  this will only be appended once
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    .selectAll("defs")
    .data(["defs"], function (d) { return d }).enter()
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    .append("svg:defs")
        .selectAll("marker")
        .data(predicates)
        .enter().append("svg:marker")
            .attr("id", String)
            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 30)
            .attr("refY", 0)
            .attr("markerWidth", 4)
            .attr("markerHeight", 4)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("svg:path")
            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Problem
    //  another g element is added to the document every update
    //Solution:
    //  create a data join on the g and class it .paths 
    //  append the path g on the resulting enter selection
    //  this will only be appeneded once
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Link bag
    //UPDATE
    paths = svg
        .selectAll(".paths")
        .data(["paths_g"]);
    //ENTER
    paths.enter()
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        .append("svg:g")

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        .attr("class", "paths");
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Links
    //UPDATE
    path = paths    //Replace svg with paths///////////////////////////////////////////////
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(links);

    path.enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index; })
            .attr("class", function (d) { return "link " + d.type; })
            .attr("marker-end", function (d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

    path.exit().remove();

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Problem
    //  another g structure is added every update
    //Solution:
    //  create a data join on the g and class it .labels 
    //  append the labels g on the resulting enter selection
    //  this will only be appeneded once
    //  include .exit().remove() to be defensive
    //Note:
    //  don't chain .enter() on the object assigned to path_label
    //  .data(...) returns an update selection which includes enter() and exit() methods
    //  .enter() returns a standard selection which doesn't have a .exit() member
    //  this will be needed if links are removed or even if the node indexing changes
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Link labels bag
    //UPDATE
    var path_labels = svg.selectAll(".labels")
            .data(["labels_g"]);
    //ENTER
    path_labels.enter()
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        .append("svg:g")

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        .attr("class", "labels");
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Link labels
    //UPDATE
    var path_label = path_labels
        .selectAll(".path_label")
        .data(links);
    //ENTER
    path_label
        .enter().append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "path_label")
            .append("svg:textPath")
                .attr("startOffset", "50%")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "#" + d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index; })
                .style("fill", "#000")
                .style("font-family", "Arial")
                .text(function (d) { return d.type; });

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    path_label.exit().remove();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Problem
    //  another g structure is added every update
    //Solution:
    //  create a data join on the g and class it .circles 
    //  append the labels g on the resulting enter selection
    //  this will only be appeneded once
    //  include .exit().remove() to be defensive
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Nodes bag
    //UPDATE
    var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
                .data(["circles_g"]);
    //ENTER
    circles.enter()
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        .append("svg:g")

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        .attr("class", "circles");
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Nodes
    //UPDATE
    circle = circles
        .selectAll(".node") //select on class instead of tag name//////////////////////////
        .data(nodes);
    circle                              //don't chain in order to keep the update selection////////////
        .enter().append("svg:circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                return node_colors[d.types[0]];
            })
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.types.indexOf("Document") == 0 ? 24 : 12; })
            .attr("stroke", "#000")
            .on("click", clicked)
            .on("dblclick", dblclick)
            .on("contextmenu", cmdclick)
            .call(force.drag);

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    circle.exit().remove();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Anchors bag
    //UPDATE
    var textBag = svg.selectAll(".anchors")
                .data(["anchors_g"]);
    //ENTER
    textBag.enter()
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        .append("svg:g")

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        .attr("class", "anchors");

    //Anchors
    //UPDATE
    text = textBag
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        .selectAll(".anchor")
            .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.name});
var textEnter = text            //don't chain in order to keep the update selection//////////
        .enter()
        .append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "anchor")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

//ADD//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    text.exit().remove;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
    textEnter.append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", 8)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .attr("class", "shadow")
            .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

    textEnter.append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", 8)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

    // calling force.drag() here returns the drag _behavior_ on which to set a listener
    // node element event listeners
    force.drag().on("dragstart", function (d) {
        d3.selectAll(".dbox").style("z-index", 0);
        d3.select("#dbox" + d.index).style("z-index", 1);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cool, you went above and beyond here with your revised code. I found that it worked, but it lost the path labels. I tinkered with that a little and got them back; the results are reflected in my on-line example. In your revision of my naming conventions, I got a little confused; however, your comments on the "General Pattern" were very instructive. Still a lot I don't get, but this is great code to study.

Comment: @jjon you can fix the path labels by adding one line of code, I have updated the revised code section to fix this.  In your latest version the labels are not coming with the added links by the way.  The one line revision takes care of that as well.

Comment: @jjon added minimum revised code preserving your naming convention.  I wanted to do this anyway to make sure I understood the minimum requirements.

Comment: thanks again @coolblue. My online example has been revised with your code verbatim. I will continue to tinker on that for a little while, but it will not persist online for very long. The commented code in your answer, however, because it is so comprehensive, will continue to be useful even in the absence of the online example. Thanks!